# Cannot move tag to front

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tags to a question should reorderable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74589/tags-to-a-question-should-reorderable)

i am trying to move the email tag to the front on the question [anonymous links in email](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3674/665)? But my edits are just lost. Even removing it and readding it does not work and does not show up in the edit history. I saved about 5 edits and it only shows one. And the email tag is still not the first one.

Answer (score 4):

The tags associated with a question are ordered by their popularity in the display (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74589/tags-to-a-question-should-reorderable)).  [email](/questions/tagged/email) on your site, IT Security, has a low volume of posts.  Only [16](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) questions have been marked with it.